# ExecutorService Execptions and memory leak?

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-leaks, executorservice

I'm doing an optimization problem in which I want to execute each Solver thread (one at a time) with random parameters for a fixed period of time. If any of the thread successfully finds a solution, it would return and the program will exit.

I have the code below where I used an ExecutorService and Future to help me accomplish this. However, for some reason, the memory usage of the program increases linearly as time goes on, and the program will terminate with an OutOfMemory error before it gets very far. My Solver code is certainly not the issue as it has no static variables and uses a constant amount of memory. I'm wondering if it's because I'm not cleaning up the threads or handling the exceptions properly, but I can't seem to find any egregious problem from the code.

```
public class RandomizedSolver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Starting new thread");
                    Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Solver(args));
                    future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    break;
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread timeout.");
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the `Solver` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of using ExecutorServices is to reuse their threads, not to keep recreating them. You should revise your design and have only one ExecutorService, with the appropriate number of underlying threads, and submit all you tasks to that unique ExecutorService.

Also note that if your tasks take more than 1 seconds and if they do not terminate promptly when interrupted, you could have up to 300 ExecutorServices and 300 Solver tasks running at the same time. Depending on how much memory you Solver takes, that could result in a OOME.